# Не вызывается фортрановская функция в cи / (не линкуется фортрановская либа?)

Tags: c++, c, cmake, fortran, clion

Почему не линкуется данный проект?

есть main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
    void showm(void);
}
int main (void) {
    showm();
    return 0;
}
```

Есть fort.f90

```
subroutine showm
print *, "fort "
end subroutine showm
```

Собираю через cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(main)
enable_language(CXX)
enable_language (Fortran)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(FORTRAN_SOURCES fort.f90)
add_library(F_OBJECTS_LIB ${FORTRAN_SOURCES})
add_executable(main ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(main F_OBJECTS_LIB)
```

В итоге линкер выдает ошибку:

> /home/mk/clion-2016.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build
>   /home/mk/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/proba-
>   c5f6dd60/c5f6dd60/Debug --target all -- -j 2 [ 50%] Built target
>   F_OBJECTS_LIB Scanning dependencies of target main [ 75%] Building CXX
>   object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o [100%] Linking CXX executable
>   main CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function main':
>   /home/mk/Рабочий стол/proba/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to
>   showm()' collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата
>   1

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, что я делаю неверно.

Comment: А фортрановская библиотека-то у вас собралась? Судя по выводу - нет.

Comment: Фортрановская библиотека собралась

Answer (score 2):

Для билда под unix верно описывать функцию вот так:

```
subroutine showm bind(C,name="showm")
print *, "fort "
end subroutine showm
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте символ `_` к названию фортрановской функции:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
    void showm_(void); // showm -> showm_
}
int main (void) {
    showm_();          // showm -> showm_
    return 0;
}
```

Уж не знаю, почему так, но это работает. Буду рад, если кто пояснит.

Comment: aleks.andr, такое работает только на windows

Comment: В unix при объявлении фортрановской функции нужно писать 
    subroutine showm bind(C,name="showm")
    print *, "fort "
    end subroutine showm
Вот теперь все заработало, всем спасибо

Comment: если это intel fortran, то у него ассемблерные имена управляются опциями: большие/маленькие символы, подчеркивание: спереди/сзади/нет. Потому что например VC++ в x86 имеет спереди черту, а в x64 не имеет